# Segmentation fault with pointr

Tags: c, pointers

Why I get on Segmentation fault for this code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int *ptr;
    *ptr =24;
     if(*ptr < 12)
        printf("************** 1\n");
     if(*ptr > 64)
      printf("************** 2");
 }
```

update:
I need to compare the value of pointer *ptr =24; with the if statement, there is no output!

```
 int data = 24;
    int *ptr =&data;
     if(*ptr < 12){
    printf("************** 1\n");
    }
   if(*ptr > 64)
  {
      printf("************** 2");
  }
```

Comment: `ptr =24;` You are using `24` as an address. Obviously that is not a valid memory location and hence dereferencing it results in Undefined Behaviour. What exactly are you trying to do and why do you think that should work?

Comment: The first part of the answer in the linked duplicate answers the vast majority of these kind of questions: _"A pointer is a special type of variable, which can only contain an address of another variable. It cannot contain any data. You cannot "copy/store data into a pointer" - that doesn't make any sense. You can only set a pointer to point at data allocated elsewhere."_

Comment: I need to compare the value of pointer *ptr =24;
with the if statement

Comment: Maybe read what I just wrote instead.